# Failed to login when creating DataSet from DataStore using Azure Machine Learning Designer

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm new to Azure and its ML Designer.  I have an Azure SQL Database set up with my Client IP allowed through the Firewall.  I can connect using SSMS without issue using the server path and credentials Azure supplied.

I have set up a Machine Learning Resource and launched the Learning Studio.

Inside the Learning Studio I created a DataStore pointing to my Azure SQL Database and everything seems just fine:

[Azure SQL Database DataStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If0Le.png)

However, when I try to create a DataSet from that DataStore I am getting Login errors:

[Login error when creating DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtlyQ.png)

In "More details" I see the following:

> ScriptExecutionException was caused by DatabaseConnectionException.\n  DatabaseConnectionException was caused by AuthenticationException.\n    'MSSQl' encountered connection erro with error code '18456' while opening connection to server ([REDACTED]), database ([REDACTED]). Either the database name is not valid or username and password is wrong. Exception class: '14'. HResult: x80131904.\n      Failed due to inner exception of type: SqlException\n

I am sure the database name and login credentials are correct i.e. they work just fine when connecting from my SSMS.  What else can this be?  I've checked the Azure SQL Database profile - is there something here regarding security or access that I should be setting?

[Firewall Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZJUc.png)

** UPDATE **
Solved this by going to SQL Server > Active Directory admin.  There was nothing set here so I clicked Set Admin and then from the right panel scrolled down to the ML service I had set up.  Once I saved it and then created a Dataset in ML I could see the data Preview just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get a preview of the dataset, it goes through Azure ML's service. If the only kind of restriction are IP restrictions (nothing around vnets/private links), then you can add [Azure ML's IP ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) to your network settings.

Alternatively, you can choose to "**skip validation**" where Microsoft will not parse the data while trying to create the dataset, but this means preview won't be shown.

Furthermore, ensure that you have [created a server-level IP firewall rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/design-first-database-tutorial#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule) in the firewall settings and allowed access to the server, entered valid authentication details when creating the datastore, and specified a valid table when querying your database.

**Note**: I was able to connect successfully using above guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I remain confused - sorry!  When troubleshooting this I have tried Skipping Validation but that only means the Dataset is created but fails on login when I try to use it.  I see you've added a link to IP addresses but the installation instructions are unclear.  Not sure what "Please download the new json file every week and perform the necessary changes at your site to correctly identify services running in Azure" means.  And why would I have to do this anyway? I find it amazing that MS cannot link ML to SQL without doing this?